# Saving user login in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight, security

I have an Silverlight 4 application, that communicates with an WCF-Service. The user needs to sign on to access the WCF-Services.

Now I want to prevent the user from reentering username and password each time he starts the silverlight app. What is the best way to achieve this? I thought about cookies to save username / (hashed) passowrd, but cookies can't handle Unicode and the password is saved as Unicode.

What would you suggest?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can do some thing like after first login, save its credential in Encrypted format in Isolated Storage. When SL starts pull up that and pass that to service to validate and then login.

Answer (score 1):

[IsolatedStorage](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/isolatedstorage/)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to store a GUID (if available).

For example, if your database schema looks something like this...

```
user_id (UniqueIdentifier, primary key)
username (varchar)
password_hash (varchar)
password_salt (varchar)
```

Then I'd store the `user_id` and `username` in [IsolatedStorage](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/isolatedstorage/).  When a user returns those variables will pass into a special function in your WCF service to authenticate.

And as long as the user_id is never displayed to users then this can be a secure method with no chance of compromising the password.  By the way, I came up with this idea originally for a site that uses OpenID and therefore has no passwords.

Comment: As I hash the user password (SHA256), why is there a need for the unique identifier? I can see no difference between an attacker is getting the hashed pwd and the GUID. With both informations she would be able to access the application and with both she cannot know the password used by the user, or am I wrong?

Comment: There is no difference in security, it's just another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a Silverlight app, why not just let ASP.NET handle the authentication for you? You can still secure your WCF services to only work with an authenticated user. [Here's an excellent article on the subject.](http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2008/11/Understanding-WCF-Services-in-Silverlight-2)

EDIT

I should mention that in this article the author adds custom message headers for the user name /password. I just replaced that logic with checking if the `HttpContext.Current.User` was authenticated, and if so, then allow access to the service.